# How to Catch "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling

I am concatenating column cells with a script' some of the concatenated strings for some cells after concatenation are longer than `50,000` characters.

When I try to postback data to the sheet, I get

`Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell.`

Is there a way to flag this error?

I want to output `"Too many words!"` for those cells when I run into them.

Comment: Can you provide the sample script with a test sheet with dummy values for us to replicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should craft your own validation, i.e. by using an `if` statement, then you might use a `Ui.alert()` or `Ui.showDialog()` or a `throw` statement

Example

```
if(value.length > 50E3){
  throw new Error("Too many words!")
} else {
  // put here the what should be done if length is less than 50,000
}
```

Related

- [Google Script: "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45156880/1595451)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728828/1595451

Comment: Thank you, that is a helpful solution. One I can use in general